# python regex not matching when regex tools indicate it should

Tags: python, regex

I have an if statement in a script to see if a directory given via argparse is a UNC path. But does not end with a trailing slash.

```
import re

#dest is set by argparse. but for this purpose i'll set it manually.
#originally i was escaping each \ in dest. But I found that argparse left them alone.
dest = '\\server-name\folder\subfolder'

if re.match ('^\\+[\w\W]+', dest ) and not re.match( '^\\+[\w\W]+\\$', dest):
    dest = dest + '\\'
```

I've been playing with this in ipython. The first statement is failing to match. I used the RxToolkit in Komodo IDE, it shows the regex as matching. I tried this webtool: http://www.pythonregex.com/ it matches as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing this to the re:

```
^\+[\w\W]+
```

Because `\\` means `\`. What you need to do is to raw your regex strings, by using `r`:

```
if re.match(r'^\\+[\w\W]+', dest ) and not re.match(r'^\\+[\w\W]+\\$', dest):
            ^                                       ^
```

Answer (score 4):

The string `"\\"` represent a single backslash `\`.

```
>>> print('\\')
\
```

You need to escape `\` or should use raw string literal to represent two backslashes.

```
>>> print('\\\\')
\\
>>> print(r'\\')
\\
```

BTW, [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) check for match at the beginning of the string; you can omit the leading `^`.